# Redirected too many times - Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I need to create different redirects on my nodejs app

This is my code:

```
app.get('/hello', function(req, res, next) {
  var url = req.hostname;

  if(url.indexOf('localhost') !== -1){
    res.render('hello');
  }
  else if(url.indexOf('webtest') !== -1){
    res.redirect('https://www.webtest.com/hello');
  }
  else {
    res.redirect('https://www.mainsite.com/hello');
  }
});
```

When I test this locally, it works well, but once I deploy and I try to access the link I get the error of `redirected you too many times`

How can I prevent site to redirect too many times?

Comment: So you're saying that when you deploy it to `www.mainsite.com` it just loops? That **is** exactly what you told it to do.

Comment: @Quentin  Oh, I see what you say.. because it's already on that page.

Why I'm doing that is because I have some subdomains, so when you navigate to other pages, I need to remove the subdomain and go back to mainsite/hello instead of subdomain.mainsite/hello

Answer (score 0):

What your code is doing is the following:

```
app.get('/hello', function(req, res, next) {
  var url = req.hostname;

  // If, and ONLY if we are on localhost, then display an output to end-user...
  if(url.indexOf('localhost') !== -1){
    res.render('hello');
  }
  // If we are on https://www.webtest.com/hello, then redirect to https://www.webtest.com/hello...
  else if(url.indexOf('webtest') !== -1){
    res.redirect('https://www.webtest.com/hello');
  }
  // If we are on https://www.mainsite.com/hello, then redirect to https://www.mainsite.com/hello...
  else {
    res.redirect('https://www.mainsite.com/hello');
  }
  // ...And there is no "fallback" to display outpout to end-user after a redirection.
});
```

As you can see:

1. Your conditions, by definition, generate infinite redirections
2. When end-user eventually landed on the right page, there is no instruction to send back an output, except in local mode

To avoid that, what you can do is:
    app.get('/hello', function(req, res, next) {
      var url = req.hostname;

```
  // When user is already on https://www.mainsite.com/hello, there is no need for additional redirection, thus we just send back the output.
  if(url.indexOf('localhost') || url.indexOf('mainsite') !== -1){
    res.render('hello');
  }
  // If we are on any subdomain different than www.webtest.com, perform redirection.
  else if(url.indexOf('webtest') !== -1 && url !== 'www.webtest.com'){
    res.redirect('https://www.webtest.com/hello');
  }
  else {
    res.redirect('https://www.mainsite.com/hello');
  }
});
```